# Cant import files into subversion with netbeans

Tags: svn, netbeans

I am new to programming. I am developing a program in my computer and laptop and want to keep the code in sync in both the machines. I fount out about subversion.

When I try to import a project from netbeans to subverion it is asking me repository url.

I searched over net but could not find out how to create repository using subverion and what url I have to give.

One more thing.

I just want the code to be in sync I dont need the versions. Is there any simpler solution for this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up a subversion server which is not included in Netbeans. Netbeans itself contains only a client. Just google for "set up subversion" and you'll find plenty tutorials for whatever system you are using.

You might say at the moment you don't need the versions but that's going to change when you are encountering the first time this moment where everything is screwed up in your local copy and you just want to restart from your last commit. If you are really sure that you won't need versioning you might consider using a USB stick.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want synchronization between different computers, SVN might not be the best fitting tool for you. SVN is a complete version control system with a lot of benefits for team development, although a single programmer can benefit as well.

If you have a good internet connection I would consider a cloud service like Dropbox for synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.tour.importing) will tell you how to create a repository from files on your local machine. You will need to have access to a Subversion server.

You might be better off starting with something like [uberSVN](http://www.ubersvn.com/), which will do the hard work for you and gives you an easy interface to navigate (it will install Subversion and Apache for you). You'd then use netbeans as a client to access the repository.